# Take the First record from each customer in sql

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have created the temp table in stored procedure and stored following entry in that table. Refer the entry below

Table Name - CustomerOrderList

```
 customerid | customer Name | address | Order id | price | quantity 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 2343        | xxxx          | address1| 3123     | 34    | 3
 2343        | xxxx          | address1| 3123     | 35    | 2
 2343        | xxxx          | address1| 3122     | 23    | 1
 4343        | YYYY          | address2| 3234     | 65    | 5
 4343        | YYYY          | address2| 3433     | 34    | 4
 4555        | ZZZZ          | address3| 3232     | 45    | 3
```

Need to get the following result

```
 customerid | customer Name | address | Order id | price | quantity 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 2343        | xxxx          | address1| 3123     | 34    | 3
 4343        | YYYY          | address2| 3234     | 65    | 5
 4555        | ZZZZ          | address3| 3232     | 45    | 3
```

Please suggest the sql query for that.

I am used the below query for getting the first record for each customer
select * from  @TempProductInfo 
group by customerid

get the following error

invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please help me for getting my requirement

Comment: pick mysql or sql server

Comment: How are you selecting `order id`s when there are multiple values for the same `customerid`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Looks like *SQL-Server* `select * from @TempProductInfo`, that because table variable,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in *SQL-Server* you can use `ROW_NUMBER` something like:

```
select * 
from (
    select customerid, [customer Name], address, [Order id], price, quantity,
           row_number() over(partition by customerid order by customerid, price) rn
    from @TempProductInfo 
    ) x
where rn = 1
```